# Audio stream from raspberry pi using ffserver

Tags: http, raspberry-pi, audio-streaming, ffserver

have went along lot of methods to stream audio from Raspberry pi **mic** input, But i failed to get that completed.

I tried with *avserver, ffserver,* That only get and store the audio file in raspberry pi or stream local file but not from mic input..

I know i does not know the proper code/command for **avserver** but i searched and tried all the methods i can..

I have also seen many post related to this, but no one has proper answers..

Comment: I don't recall the raspberry pi having a mic input, only an output. Did you plug a mic into the 3.5mm *output*?

Comment: Yes, Ofcourse.. Plugged in via USB

Comment: ahh, have you looked at alsamixer to make sure its there?

Comment: Yes.. It has alsa player. I need the proper command to start audio streaming from pi. Eg. avconv -i hd,0,1 mp3 -o http://localhost:8081/live.mp3